# Best ways to parse a filename independent of the OS?

Tags: java

I have an input on a Mac:

```
/Users/huyvo/Desktop/demo
```

Of course the input String would be different on a windows.

I want to isolate "demo" and return "demo"

```
String getPackageName(String path){

       String packageName = // do something

       return packageName; 
}
```

How would do it so my algorithm works on a Mac and a PC??

Comment: What's the input on windows?

Comment: It sounds like there are some other questions around what you're doing here. What programming language are you working in? Do you just want to parse a string with `/` delimiters, or do you want to portably work with file pathnames? Is the notion of a "package" relevant here? Where is the input string coming from? Is it always going to be a path following the native OS conventions? And so on.

Comment: I really don't have a Computer Science vocabulary to be honest. I just know I need to manipulate the String. I forgot Java is platform independent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [File.getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName())

> Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. This is just the last name in the pathname's name sequence. If the pathname's name sequence is empty, then the empty string is returned.

```
static String getFilename(String path) {
    return new File(path).getName();
}
```

I suggest you have a look at the class in `java.lang` `java.util` and `java.io` so you know which back classes are available in Java.

Comment: What if input = "/Users/huyvo/Desktop/untitled/demo"?

Comment: @user6212007 what is your doubt?

Comment: Nevermind. Yeah it works. Thanks. You are very smart.

Comment: @user6212007 not smart, an expert is some one who has made all the mistake before.  I have just been coding for 30 years. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `File.separator` - that give `/` under Unix, Linux, and `\` under Windows...